# add delay in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

I need to add a delay inside a loop into this javascript code but can't figure out how :

```
var hossam = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy');

for (var i = 0; i < hossam.length; i++) {
    hossam[i].click();
}

alert('[hossam] ' + hossam.length + ' people are now unfollowed! >:) ');
```

Comment: It looks like there's a loop

Comment: why you want to add delay in for loop any reason?

Comment: Pls, clarify what you exactly want. Add delay between each `for` iteration? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: As for delays, you don't just stick a delay in -- JS doesn't like running synchronously.  If you did, most browsers would appear to freeze til the loop finished, and then you'd see all the changes at once anyway.

Comment: @Girish: this is a question-and-answer site; I don't think it's your place to ask _why_ he wants this functionality, but simply to help solve his problem. I always feel a degree of frustration when people ask _why_ I want something rather than helping me. For all you know, the script in his question is an incredibly simplified abstraction of the real problem he's working on.

Comment: @awj: This is a question-and-answer site aimed at providing non-crappy answers.  It's not our place to sit by and watch someone go about solving the wrong problem.  I think it's *entirely* appropriate to ask why they're going down that road, and to steer them in a different direction if what they're literally asking for isn't the best answer.

Comment: @awj we all are for help, `op` has not mentioned problem, he only saying **add delay in loop** so i have asked to add real issue, how can you provide solution without problem??

Comment: I need to add a delay into "for" loop so i get one click per second.
I know about browser freeze and this not a problem for me.

Comment: You don't need to know the problem to answer my question i asked a clear question.

Comment: @Gio Read my question again i didn't ask to "add a loop"! i aksed how to add delay into a loop!!

Comment: @user205537 see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: @user205537: Read your own question again.  It says, word-for-word, "I need to add a loop into this javascript code but can't figure out how".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a recursive function call with a delay.

```
i = 0;
DELAY_IN_MILLISEC = 1000;

function foo() {
    if (i++ < hossam.length) {
        hossam[i].click();
        setTimeout(function(){foo()}, DELAY_IN_MILLISEC);
    }
}

foo();
```

Comment: `setTimeout` takes milliseconds as the second param, not seconds. Consequently your answer incurs a delay of 1 millisecond between each pass.

Comment: Haven't you missed some invocation of `foo()`? And where does `i` get incremented? If this answer is intended to be placed inside the OP's `for` loop then why is `i` declared, and why the need for `foo()`?

Comment: [a] foo() is called by setTimeout (corrected) [b] i gets incremented here: `if (i++ < hossam.length) {` [c] My recommendation is to use a recursive method to achieve the desired behavior because it is not possible to achieve the desired behavior through a for loop. My comment regarding your proposed anwser explains why.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see the inner (recursive) `foo()` call. However, aren't you still missing an invocation kick things off?

Comment: Yes `foo()` needs to be called in order to kick things off (added).

Comment: Why not just change `foo` to an IIFE? _I.e._, `var foo = function () { ...}();` Then you can place all three declarations in a single `var` statement (which you've also omitted).

Comment: [a] I'm sure things can be refactored to less code, but this doesn't necessarely provided a better explanation. [b] var is not necessary in this case, `i` and `DELAY_IN_MILLISEC` are both in global scope.